# I need help for Epsilon constraint method for Cplex

Tags: cplex

I need input objective and subject below into CPLEX. But I don’t know how to input. Please help me! Thanks a lot.

```
Objective 1 : min f1
Objective 2: max f2
Objective 3: min f3
Subject to:
Sum Xik=1
Sum Xii=p
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely broad. So I can only give very generic answers:

- there is an introduction to OPL, the modeling language on top of CPLEX, at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllanguser/topics/opl_languser_intro.html.
- if you consider using a programming language, please have a look at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/preface/dataEntry.html
- and if you want to directly generate a file that CPLEX can read, you should look into https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/homepages/reffileformatscplex.html for the `LP` and `MPS` file formats.